# FMDB - executeQuery Unable to provide paramaters

Tags: ios, fmdb

Code that works:

```
A) FMResultSet *r = [self.db executeQuery:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myDB"];
```

What I want to work:

```
B) r = [self.db executeQuery:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ?",@"myDB"];
```

The error when using `B`:

```
DB Error: 1 "near "?": syntax error"
DB Query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ?
```

How can I get `B` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can pass table name in a parameterised query.

As an alternative you can do it like:

```
- (void)queryBuilder:(NSString *)tableName
{
   NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %@",tableName];
   return result;
}
```

And use it like:

```
r = [self.db executeQuery:[self queryBuilder:@"myDB"]];
```

Comment: That's a bummer. Thanks.